# R: Pivot longer by combining the columns based on a factor

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame that has four columns. I'd like to use some kind of pivot_longer (like in tidyr) but to combine each value of the four columns two by two based on an id.

For example if I have

```
id     A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10     5     4     0
```

I would like to obtain:

```
  id factor_1 factor_2 value_1 value_2
1  1        A        B      10       5
2  1        A        C      10       4
3  1        A        D      10       0
4  1        B        C       5       4
5  1        B        D       5       0
6  1        C        D       4       0
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Best.

Comment: I am not sure, but there might be some errors in the cold, in the example, there are five elements in the header and six elements in the data row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer()` is one piece, but you'll still need to generate the pairwise combinations. Code below uses a self join using `inner_join()`, but there are several other ways to tackle that piece.

```r
    library("tidyverse")
    df <- tribble(
      ~id, ~A, ~B, ~C, ~D,
      1, 10, 5, 4, 0)
    df_longer <- df %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = c(A, B, C, D), names_to = "factor", values_to = "value") 
    df_longer %>%
      inner_join(df_longer, by = "id", suffix = c("_1", "_2")) %>%
      filter(factor_1 < factor_2)
    #> # A tibble: 6 x 5
    #>      id factor_1 value_1 factor_2 value_2
    #>   <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
    #> 1     1 A             10 B              5
    #> 2     1 A             10 C              4
    #> 3     1 A             10 D              0
    #> 4     1 B              5 C              4
    #> 5     1 B              5 D              0
    #> 6     1 C              4 D              0
```

Comment: thank you very much ravic. i didnt think about the inner join like that.